# Creating video thumbnail with ffmpeg from buffer

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, buffer, video-thumbnails

Attempting to create a child process which spawns ffmpeg command. Should use the buffer from fs.readFile to write to stdin. The `-i -` flag tells ffmpeg to source input from stdin but nothing is happening when running this code.

If replace `-i -` with `-i test.mp4` this script works perfectly.

What is wrong with the write to stdin which is not allowing code to generate thumbnail?

```
(async () => {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const fs = require('fs/promises');
    const buffer = await fs.readFile('test.mp4');
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('Spawning process');
        const process = spawn('ffmpeg',
            [
                '-ss', '00:00:01',
                '-i', '-',
                '-s', '256x256',
                '-vframes', '1',
                '-f', 'image2',
                'output.png'
            ]);
        process.stdin.write(buffer);
        process.stdin.end();
        process.on('close', (done) => {
            console.log("Process closed: ", done);
            resolve();
        });
    });
})();
```

Edit:

Also tried this:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
module.exports =
    async (stream) => {
        ffmpeg(stream)
        .addOption('-f','rawvideo')
        .inputFormat('mov')
        .toFormat('mp4')
        .thumbnail({
            count:1,
            size:'256x256',
            filename:'test.png',
            timemarks:["00:00:03"]
        })
        .on('stdout',(stdout)=>{
            console.log(stdout);
        })
        .on('stderr',(err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

With this error output:

```
ffmpeg version N-102781-g05f9b3a0a5 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.102 / 59.  1.102
  libavformat    59.  3.101 / 59.  3.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.102 /  8.  0.102
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025220812340] stream 0, offset 0x24: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025220812340] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(bt709), 640x360, 2630 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-07-25T11:06:03.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:17.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-25T11:06:03.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(bt709), 640x360, 2630 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)     
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-25T11:06:03.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-25T11:06:03.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-25T11:06:03.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale
  split -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025220812340] stream 1, offset 0xb1bf9: partial file
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:1 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:1 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Have you tried `'-i -',` instead of `'-i', '-',`?

Comment: Throws this error:
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EOF
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4095,
  code: 'EOF',
  syscall: 'write'
}

Comment: @J.Carpenter Did you find any method for this situation?

Comment: @HyopeR I am currently using video-thumb npm package to generate thumbnails from a file instead of a buffer. I found a channel to contact ffmpeg devs and they said mp4 needs to be read by ffmpeg from disk since there is metadata that needs to be read at the end of the file and can not be processed as a buffer.